# Tenant model with subdomains in ingress-nginx controller

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I need to create tenant model using ingress-nginx. We need every dealer has own subdomain. For example, we have endpoint in frontend host:

https://example.com/dealers/<some_dealer>/<additional_path>

I want each dealer have own subdomain, for example

https://<some_dealer>.example.com/<additional_path>

I've used proxy_pass using nginx, but have no idea how to do it using ingress-nginx controller in Kubernetes.

My ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: development
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - "*.example.com"
      secretName: example-certificate-secret
  ingressClassName: example-class-resource
  rules:
    - host: dealer1.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: example
              port:
                name: https
```

I was trying to using annotations such as nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to, adding proxy_pass using server-snipper annotations

Comment: Are you running a separate instance of the backend service for each dealer as well?